# How do I make my 305 GB drive my default drive?

Tags: disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I let it run from 10 GB.  Now I have run out of space by using 10 GB of data, but I have another 305 on my default hard drive.  How do I make all that data go onto that disk so I can have more space?

Answer (score 0):

If the 305 GB free space is right after the 10 GB partition, you can extend the latter to cover the former. If it isn't, one easy way would be to just move the `/home` directory to a new partition inside the free space, leaving the system in the 10 GB partition (which is not quite a lot, but could suffice). Of course, you can bring out `/tmp` too.

You can use `fdisk`, `gnome-disks` or `gparted` (easiest) to modify the partitions and reconfigure `/etc/fstab` without manually editing it.